# Error when creating virtual environment, "(Directory/Path), '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 101."

Tags: python, virtualenv, windows-11

When I enter `py -m venv venv` into Git Bash it comes up with an error, `Error: Command '['C:\\Users\\admin\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\ll_env\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 101.` It is very weird since I have been creating lots of virtual environments, and only now did this happen

Comment: it might be due to it being in onedrive, try creating a venv outside the onedrive and see if it still has the same issue

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: What is the difference to the other vens? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Have you checked the bug reports for the involved software?